# object not stopping at target location

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have a game where you click and the object moves to it. It stops at the target sometimes but other times keep going... I'm really confused to what might be causing this issue. Hopefully its not something easy xD as I've been coding for a while now. Any ideas/tips feel free to leave in the comments. ;)

#### Mouse

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    c.x = e.getX();
    c.y = e.getY();

    if (unit == false) {
        if (s == false) {
            for (Hazmat h1 : outbreak.hazmat) {
                if (c.getBounds().intersects(h1.bounds) || c.contains(h1.bounds)) {
                    selected = h1;
                    s = true;
                    unit = true;
                    Info.log("Selected unit. (First)");

                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        selected.re = true;

        Info.log("Sending unit to location!");
        targetX = e.getX();
        targetY = e.getY();
        selected.targetX = e.getX();
        selected.targetY = e.getY();

        float xSpeed = (targetX - (float) selected.x) / .1f;
        float ySpeed = (targetY - (float) selected.y) / .1f;
        float factor = (float) (1.0f / Math.sqrt(xSpeed * xSpeed + ySpeed * ySpeed));
        xSpeed *= factor;
        ySpeed *= factor;
        selected.velx = xSpeed;
        selected.vely = ySpeed;
        s = false;
        unit = false;
        Info.log("-----------------");
        Info.log("xSpeed: " + xSpeed);
        Info.log("ySpeed: " + ySpeed);
        Info.log("Factor: " + factor);
        Info.log("TargetX: " + targetX);
        Info.log("TargetY: " + targetY);
        Info.log("-----------------");
    }
}
```

#### Object

```
x += velx;
y += vely;
bounds.x = (int) x;
bounds.y = (int) y;

if (re == true) {
    if (bounds.x == targetX && bounds.y == targetY) {
        velx = 0;
        vely = 0;
        Info.log("[!] Target Point Reached [!]");
        re = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking if two floating point values are equal oftentimes runs into problems of very small precision errors. The values `bounds.x` and `targetX` might be `0.00000001` points apart, but your check `bounds.x == targetX` would fail.

Instead, try something like this:

```
if ((bounds.x - targetX) < 0.0001 && (bounds.y - targetY) < 0.0001)
```

Comment: I did this, and i understand your point(Thank you) but now the object dosnt move at all. But i though of just rounding the target x and y and the object x and y but that still dosnt work some of the time

Comment: You can make a threshold variable and use that. `double threshold = 0.0001d;` :)